# Run Powershell Command from Oracle Procedure

Tags: android, oracle, powershell, oracle12c

I need to print pdf documents to my network printer from my android studio application. I want to print the pdf as is with all images and formatting, however, the solutions I have found only allow for the extraction and printing of text from the pdf.

I have also seen solutions mentioning tools like Ghostscript etc which are supposed to convert the pdf to a postscript file, but these tools do not work with Android Studio or at-least I haven't figured out how to integrate them into my application. I cannot pay for tools like jPDFPrint which does exactly what I need.

I started thinking about a work around and came upon the idea of sending my pdf as a blob to my oracle database and invoke a power shell command from a procedure to print it to a specific printer.

I've created and tested the below command to print to my network printer from my PC which works great.

```
    Start-Process -FilePath “c:\test.pdf” –Verb PrintTo '\\PrintServer\PrinterName' -PassThru | %{sleep 10;$_} | kill
```

Now I need help with the oracle part. Is it possible to invoke or run a powershell command from within oracle 12c and pass it the pdf blob as well as the printer name?

Comment: What OS is he database on? Poweshell implies you want this run on Windows.

Comment: @TenG Sorry for not specifying. I have a windows environment. Windows Server 2016 to be exact.

Comment: To clarify, do you need to pass the BLOB itself to Oracle, or the path to the PDF?

Comment: @TenG I envision passing the blob and printer name from my android app to my oracle procedure then run the script within the procedure to print. Ideally I don't want to  store anything in the database or file system of the database server.

Comment: Trying to be clear before I attempt to help. The android app will save a blob to a Oracle database, with a printer name. Then something, a job, will extract this blob to a PDF file, and issue a powershell command on the Oracle database server which is Win 2016. RIght?

Comment: @TenG :O I didn't realize I needed to re-create the pdf file after getting it to the oracle side. I got only as far as saving the file into a table. I'm researching sample codes on how to extract the blob and re-create the pdf file. So yes after re-creating the file, I would like to issue a powershell command to print the document from my oracle database which is installed on Win2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the BLOB to a PDF.

Create you system folder, eg `c:\printthis`.

Then create the Oracle directory object mapped to this folder:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY print_dir AS 'C:\print_this';

GRANT READ WRITE ON DIRECTORY print_dir TO PUBLIC;
```

This procedure to extract the BLOB to a file.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE extract_pdf ( p_id IN VARCHAR2 ) AS
   CURSOR c1 IS 
      SELECT doc_blob, doc_name
      FROM doc_table
      WHERE doc_id = p_id;
   r1         c1%ROWTYPE;
   v_size     NUMBER( 5,0) := 32000;
   v_len      NUMBER(38,0);
   v_buffer   RAW(32000);
   v_file     UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
   OPEN c1;
   FETCH c1 INTO r1;
   v_file  := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('PRINT_DIR', r1.doc_name, 'wb', 32760 );
   v_start := 1;
   v_len   := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH( r.bbl_fic );
   WHILE v_start <= v_len LOOP
      DBMS_LOB.READ(
             r.bbl_fic,
             LEAST( v_len - v_start + 1, v_size ),
             v_start,
             v_buffer
           );
      UTL_FILE.PUT_RAW( v_file, v_buffer );
      UTL_FILE.FFLUSH( v_file ); 
      v_start := v_start + v_size;
    END LOOP;
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE( v_file );
--  Write the CMD file
    v_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('PRINT_DIR', r1.doc_name || '.bat', 'w' );
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(     'Start-Process -FilePath “c:\print_this\' || r1.doc_name || '” –Verb PrintTo '\\PrintServer\PrinterName' -PassThru | %{sleep 10;$_} | kill' );
    UTL_FILE.CLOSE(v_file);
END;
/
```

A Windows At job that runs, polls the `c:\print_this` folder for files and runs the `.bat` command, then deletes it.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (c:\print_this\*.bat) do (
  echo "Name: %%f"
  powershell %%f
  del %%f
)
```

The question remains of how to stitch this together. Your Android app calls your procedure to store the PDF as a BLOB. It must also be able to call the procedure suggested above to extract the saved BLOB to a database server file, so this procedure to extract the ODF AND create the print bat script is called after the save BLOB.

The Task Scheduler job polls the directory for the bat scripts, runs them deletes them.

You cannot directly issue a command to the server host from within Oracle. You can use DBMS_SCHEDULER. In the above example, the job would take the doc_id as a parameter, and execute this via DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB. I cant remember how to do this precisely, but I hope my other suggestion with the Task Scheduler in Windows is fruitful for you.

Comment: Thank you so much @TenG. I appreciate your help and the example code. I will try to implement this and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PL/SQL package [DBMS_SCHEDULER](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SCHEDULER.html#GUID-F41A5779-1915-4D5D-A7F5-87727320B742) procedure create_program, using the program_type=>'EXECUTABLE' to do what you want.  Then you would have your process that sends the data to oracle create a job to invoke that program.  The DBMS_SCHEDULER package is pretty complex so you'll probably need to hunt around for tutorials/tips; you may want to search https://asktom.oracle.com for starters.

Comment: Mark's Answer is correct for invoking the powershell. But I'm a little confused as to what pushing the PDF through Oracle is giving you here anyway. Can't you invoke a similar command direct from the application?

Comment: @MArk Stewart I have tried the DBMS_SCHEDULER, but could not get it to work. The job failed whenever I ran it without giving me an error.

Comment: @Carlovski First prize for me would be doing your suggestion, but I can't seem to find a way to do it which is why I thought of the work around. If there is a way to do it from my app, would you please share it with me.

Comment: As I hinted, DBMS_SCHEDULER is very complex to set up; you probably didn't set up credentials for the job, which is basically telling Oracle what Windows user and password to use to invoke the Powershell program, and you also need to allow Oracle access to the directory where the Powershell program is, and ...  create an oracle directory etc etc